# how do I convert json schema into django models?

Tags: django

I have a few jsons with the following structure, but I want to convert in a proper way to render the following JSON schema into a Django model with its proper relationship in order to keep the same format to save its data

```
[
    {
        "Resource Development": [
            {
                "technique_id": "T1583",
                "technique": "Acquire Infrastructure",
                "tactic": [
                    "Resource Development"
                ],
                "subtechnique": [
                    {
                        "technique_id": "T1583.001",
                        "technique": "Acquire Infrastructure : Domains",
                        "url": "https://",
                        "command_list": [],
                        "queries": [],
                        "possible_detections": []
                    },

                ],
                "command_list": [],
                "queries": [],
                "possible_detections": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Serializer of [Django Rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). Reference the document [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).